# Computing standard error in weighted mean estimation

Tags: standard-error, weighted-mean

Suppose that $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n$ and $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are each drawn *i.i.d.* from some distributions, with $w_i$ independent of $x_i$. The $w_i$ are strictly positive. You observe all the $w_i$, but not the $x_i$; rather you observe $\sum_i x_i w_i$. I am interested in estimating $\operatorname{E}\left[x\right]$ from this information. Clearly the estimator
$$
\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_i w_i x_i}{\sum_i w_i}
$$
is unbiased, and can be computed given the information at hand.

How might I compute the standard error of this estimator? For the sub-case where $x_i$ takes only values 0 and 1, I naively tried
$$
se \approx \frac{\sqrt{\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})\sum_i w_i^2}}{\sum_i w_i},
$$
basically ignoring the variability in the $w_i$, but found that this performed poorly for sample sizes smaller than around 250. (And this probably depends on the variance of the $w_i$.) It seems that maybe I don't have enough information to compute a 'better' standard error.

Answer (score 22):

I ran into the same issue recently. The following is what I found:

Unlike a simple random sample with equal weights, there is no widely accepted definition of standard error of the *weighted* mean. These days, it would be straight-forward to do a bootstrap and obtain the empirical distribution of the mean, and based on that estimate the standard error.

What if one wanted to use a formula to do this estimation?

The main reference is [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/135223109400210C), by Donald F. Gatz and Luther Smith, where 3 formula based estimators are compared with bootstrap results. The best approximation to the bootstrap result comes from Cochran (1977):

$(SEM_w)^2={\dfrac{n}{(n-1)(\sum {P_i})^2}}[\sum (P_i X_i-\bar{P}\bar{X}_w)^2-2 \bar{X}_w \sum (P_i-\bar{P})(P_i X_i-\bar{P}\bar{X}_w)+\bar{X}^2_w \sum (P_i-\bar{P})^2]$

The following is the corresponding R code that came from [this R listserve thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-June/133192.html).

```
weighted.var.se <- function(x, w, na.rm=FALSE)
#  Computes the variance of a weighted mean following Cochran 1977 definition
{
  if (na.rm) { w <- w[i <- !is.na(x)]; x <- x[i] }
  n = length(w)
  xWbar = weighted.mean(x,w,na.rm=na.rm)
  wbar = mean(w)
  out = n/((n-1)*sum(w)^2)*(sum((w*x-wbar*xWbar)^2)-2*xWbar*sum((w-wbar)*(w*x-wbar*xWbar))+xWbar^2*sum((w-wbar)^2))
  return(out)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is pretty cool, but for my problem I don't even observe the $P_iX_i$, rather I observe the sum $\sum_i P_iX_i$. My question is very weird because it involves some information asymmetry (a third party is reporting the sum, and trying to perhaps hide some information).

Comment: Gosh you're right, sorry I did not fully understand the question you posed. Suppose we boil your problem down to the simplest case where all $w_i$ are Bernoulli RV. Then you are essentially observing the sum of a random subset of $n$ RVs. My guess is there is not a lot of information here to estimate with. So what did you end up doing for your original problem?

Comment: @Ming-ChihKao this cochran formula is interesting but if you build a confidence interval off this when the data is not normal there is no consistent interpretation correct?  How would you handle non-normal weighted average mean confidence intervals?  Weighted quantiles?

Comment: I think there is an error with the function. If you substitute `w=rep(1, length(x))`, then `weighted.var.se(rnorm(50), rep(1, 50))` is about `0.014`. I think the formula is missing a `sum(w^2)` in the numerator, since when `P=1`, the variance is `1/(n*(n-1)) * sum((x-xbar)^2)`. I can't check the cited article as it is behind a paywall, but I think that correction.

Oddly enough, Wikipedia's (different) solution becomes degenerate when all weights are equal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Weighted_sample_variance.

Comment: These may work better in general: http://www.analyticalgroup.com/download/WEIGHTED_MEAN.pdf

Comment: I found that the function reduces to $(SEM_w)^2 = \frac{n}{(n-1)\bar{w}^2}  \sum w_i^2(x_i - \mu^*)^2$ where $w_i =P_i$ and $\bar{w} = \sum w_i$ which is a lot easier to read. I also tested the function out with a boot-strapping method and it seems to check out. For computational purposes the following form is useful $(SEM_w)^2 = \frac{n}{(n-1)\bar{w}^2} \left( \sum w_i^2 x_i^2 - 2 \mu^* \sum w_i^2 x_i + \mu^{*2} \sum w_i^2 \right)$

Comment: This R function is incorrect. Use `Hmisc::wtd.var(x, w)` instead.

Comment: How about finite population correction?

Answer (score 8):

The variance of your estimate given the $w_i$ is
$$
\frac{\sum w_i^2 Var(X)}{(\sum w_i)^2} = Var(X) \frac{\sum w_i^2 }{(\sum w_i)^2}.
$$
Because your estimate is unbiased for any $w_i$, the variance of its conditional mean is zero. Hence, the variance of your estimate is
$$
Var(X) \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum w_i^2 }{(\sum w_i)^2}\right)
$$
With all the data observed, this would be easy to estimate empirically. But with only a measure of location of the $X_i$ observed, and not their spread, I don't see how it's going to be possible to get an estimate of $Var(X)$, without making rather severe assumptions.

Comment: at least in the specific case where $x_i$ have a Bernoulli distribution I can estimate the variance of $x$ by $\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})$ as noted above. Even in this case, as noted in the question, I need a larger sample size than I would have expected.

Answer (score 2):

@Ming K 's equation is not working for me. @Hugh mentioned  `Hmisc::wtd.var(x, w)`, but this is for variance, if you are wondering about weighted standard error, [this](https://githubmemory.com/repo/harrelfe/Hmisc/issues/138) would be useful. But read assumption and equation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Statistical_properties), following
$$
\sigma _{x}^{-} = \sigma \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\omega _{i}^{'2}}
$$

For your convenient, I copy them here.

```
wtd.stderror <- function(x, weights){
  var <- Hmisc::wtd.var(x, weights)
  weights <- sum( (weights / sum(weights))^2 )
  
  sqrt(var*weights)
}
```

But I am not sure whether this will work for dateset with a Bernoulli distribution

Comment: Please re-read the question: the $x_i$ are _not_ observed or are otherwise unavailable for this computation.

Comment: Sorry, I see, this is to supplement Ming K's and Hugh's answer